# spark Dataset select clause is not working in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, filter

I am trying to select few columns using `.select()` function of sparkAPI Java, But the Dataset takes all the available fields from the parquet file I am using.

```
List<Column> selectCols = new ArrayList<>();
selectCols.add("id");
selectCols.add("name");

dataset.filter(col("name")
  .isin('john','mary')).
   select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(selectCols).seq()));
```

But this above method gives me all available cols in the parque. How can I get only the select columns data into the dataset.

Comment: Have you tried `select("id", "name")` (without this "fancy" code)? Did something simpler work for you?

Comment: Yes Jacek. It still gets me the same result.

Comment: I hardly believe what you're saying and I'm sure it's because I don't understand the problem. How do you know that _"But the Dataset takes all the available fields from the parquet file I am using."_?

Comment: I'm writing that to csv

Comment: Edit your question with the writing part. Add `printSchema` on the dataset you save.